# SQLite Database can work on secondary dispatch async thread

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, sqlite, swift3, dispatch-async

Hello Any one have idea or code to manage sqlite database working on dispatch async task in background thread without any issue such as database locked issue.

Comment: What is the database locked issue?  While the database file is being accessed, it will be locked.  That's an issue?

Comment: while accessing database same time by multiple thread on same table.

Answer (score 0):

hope you're using a class `xyzDBMgr` to execute all the query on a `xyz.sqlite` file. say you're using `foo1`, `foo2` methods. Use `@synchronized` block upon self to lock the table and ensure thread safety.

**xyzDBMgr.m**

```
@implementation xyzDBMgr


void foo1
{
     @synchronized(self)
     {
         // your locked code goes here
     }
}

void foo2
{
     @synchronized(self)
     {
        // your locked code goes here
     }
}

...
@end
```

> Do not call lock function inside of another lock function. In case you called `foo1` inside from the `foo2` then a deadlock is obvious.

If you want to call these method from secondary thread you can use apple's GCD api calls like `dispathc_async` or NSOperationQueue api calls.